# Windows Tensorflow with Python unable to read mnist data due to permissions

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, temp, mnist

I'm using Python on windows and am following the standard tutorial for Tensorflow that requires reading the MNIST data set. Unfortunately I get the following error when trying to run:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6_cvro98'

That filename at the end changes each time the program runs. The code in question is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import mnist as input_data 

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
```

As far as I'm aware I'm running it as administrator with full access privileges on the user account. Unsure why I don't have permissions (or why it requires temp data in the first place)

Comment: I think it downloads the data set and stores it somewhere (for why it requires temp data).

Comment: That makes sense. Would there a way to change this location?

Comment: You could download it manually yourself and process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled python but this time marked the box that said 'for all users'. That seemed to solve the issue